# Adding more fields to yii2 active form on add more link

Tags: jquery, yii2-advanced-app

Can anyone help adding more fields to active form i mean i already have input boxes for name and email how do i add more name and email inputs to the yii2 active form on click of add more and do a server side validation for same.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this extension.

Demo Link : `http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo3/create`

https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform